# Can I create a process variable in the editor Camunda?

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler, bpmn.io

Started working with the Сamunda platform.
Can't find if it is possible to set process variables directly in the editor, or should I only use the provided API?

[image]

Comment: did it help? - please always give feedback to an answer - either mark it as the solution of your problem or leave a comment why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .. is possible to set process variables directly in the editor..?

Yes it is possible, there are some places you can do this - I usually do it here:

- Execution Listeners:
  [image]
- Output Parameters:
  [image]